# Reset Button Border

Tags: php, html, css, button

I'm starting to feel like it is something i'm doing something wrong since I can't find anybody else with this issue so i'm asking for assistance from you devs! Thanks in advance!

The reset button has a border around it that I want to remove. It's weird because my submit button doesn't have one:

```
<div class="contact-submit">
    <input type="image" src="images/submit-btn.png" width="93" height="33" value="Send Message">
    <button type="reset"> 
        <img src="images/reset-btn.png" width="93" height="33"/> 
    </button> 
</div>
```

Comment: You'll probably get better help if you tag all the languages you're using. Lots of us filter by the languages we have most expertise in. And do you really need the 'reset' tag? It seems like the problem is with the look of the button itself, not its resetting functionality.

Comment: In addition to tagging what languages you're using, could you post some code? The difference in the code between the submit and reset buttons is what will help us help you here.

Comment: <div class="contact-submit"><input type="image" src="images/submit-btn.png" width="93" height="33" value="Send Message">

<button type="reset">
    <img src="images/reset-btn.png" width="93" height="33"/>
 </button>
</div>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button looks like a button because it is a button. To change this look you will have override the browser button style with your own CSS style:

**CSS**

```
button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: medium none;
}
```

Comment: There we go! Thank You! I knew I had to do something with the button css but I didn't know the exact paramaters. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I took a look into your page source. In the HTML, your submit button is not actually a button, it's an input image:

```
<div class="contact-submit">
<input type="image" src="images/submit-btn.png" width="93" height="33" value="Send Message"> 
<button type="reset"> 
<img src="images/reset-btn.png" width="93" height="33"/>
</button> 
</div>
```

The reset button, on the other hand, is actually a button. If you change it to an input image, like the submit button, it should look the same. See my code below:

```
<div class="contact-submit">
<input type="image" src="images/submit-btn.png" width="93" height="33" value="Send Message"> 
<input type="image" src="images/reset-btn.png" width="93" height="33"/>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how you're handling click events, but it seems like you'll just need to add `value="Reset"` or however you have it set up to that input element.

Comment: I forgot to mention this was my original attempt...if you view the site link again http://odconnect.com/beta/contact.php and click the reset button I am now getting an error. That is why I resorted to use thing the button code that I did because that was successfully resetting the form.

I'm converting this site from it's old look and the original code was this:

<input type="reset"  value="Reset Form" />

So what would be the proper coding to have the reset function and custom image button? Sorry for not posting these details previously.

Comment: In that case, you'll simply want to change the CSS of the button. Look to the answer @My Head Hurts posted a bit after mine, he'll get you through it. I thought it would make more sense to just make the inputs the same type, thought a button is easier to code an event for.